Unity3D Resource.Load Returns Null
I am trying to get a reference to a prefab called health_bar. For some reason, it isn't load. It returns null. Have I missed something? Is the filepath wrong or is it something else?

I was trying to get a reference to a prefab yet it didn't go as expected. It returned null.

Read the documentation for Resources.Load to check what the requirements for the path are.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

You have two issues with your current Resources.Load call:

Your prefab (or whatever object) has to be placed within a Resources folder, usually Assets/Resources/. When calling Resources.Load, you don't include this folder in the string: Resources.Load("MyPrefab");

Don't include the extension, otherwise Unity will fail to find the object. (Since it searches by it's normal name, not by filename)



Try to read through the documentation first or search online when you run into issues like these, because common issues like this one are usually already in the documentation:

The path is relative to any folder named Resources inside the Assets folder of your project


Note that the path is case insensitive and must not contain a file extension


For example, a project may have Resources folders called Assets / Resources/ and Assets / Guns / Resources/.


I though I could give any arbitrary name to the folder which seems wrong. I finally made it work by changing the name of the main folder to "Resources". The problem was solved. Thank you!

@TankutZeytinoluServantOfAl after you build your application into a final executable there is no such files and folder structure anymore and assets that are no where referenced will not be included either ;) In general: Don't use Resources

@derHugo "there is no such files and folder structure anymore and assets that are no where referenced will not be included either" That's not true for the resources folder, just for normal asset folders. Resources are always included (they have to be) and can still be loaded by their relative path, even if there's no reference to them in the editor. Heck, that page even says that all resources are packed into a single assetbundle-like asset automatically.

@ipodtouch0218 I know that ^^ I tried to reply here to OP's I though I could give any arbitrary name to the folder which seems wrong

@derHugo ah, I thought you were talking about the resources folder's structure specifically. I do agree that assetbundles are better generally tho!

@ipodtouch0218 even that depends on how side-laoded and/or exchangeable you really need it to be. Most straight forward might be to simply reference the prefab via the Inspector in the first place instead of loading it from resources or asset bundle etc .. (also there is already an extension also on top of asset bundles: Addressables)
